# Get vector indexes from a list of factor vectors

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

Consider a factor vector, my.vector that has 3 levels.  If I want to get a list of vectors that contain the vector indexes for the occurrence of each level.  I can do that this way

```
vec.levels <- levels(my.vector)
factor.vectors <- map(vec.levels, function(x) which(my.vector == x))
```

That gives me a list of the 3 integer vectors corresponding to the sub-indexes of occurances for each factor level.

My question is how to make that extensible to a list of factor vectors each with a set of factor levels.  I.e., extract the factor vectors from a data frame as a subset dataframe, say my.subset and the get a list of the levels of each factor in the subset dataframe, say my.levels.list.

So how to operate on my.levels.list and my.subset to get a list of lists where the lists are the index vectors for each factor in each factor column?  In other words, looping over both lists.  Is there a way do it without an explicit loop using tidyverse or other R functions?

Hope that is clear.  Thanks for any feedback.

Thanks for the replies. So sure.  Take the dataframe df with 2 factor columns:

```
   Citrus Cutlery
1   lemon   spoon
2    lime   spoon
3    lime   spoon
4  orange   spoon
5    lime   knife
6    lime    fork
7   lemon    fork
8   lemon    fork
9    lime   spoon
10   lime    fork
11  lemon   spoon
12 orange   knife
13 orange   spoon
14  lemon   knife
15   lime   knife
16  lemon   knife
17  lemon   spoon
18 orange   spoon
19   lime   spoon
20   lime    fork
```

I can apply each factor vector individually to the above levels and map statements to yield the Citrus sub-index list:

```
[[1]]
[1]  1  7  8 11 14 16 17

[[2]]
[1]  2  3  5  6  9 10 15 19 20

[[3]]
[1]  4 12 13 18
```

And the Cutlery sub-index list:

```
[[1]]
[1]  6  7  8 10 20

[[2]]
[1]  5 12 14 15 16

[[3]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  9 11 13 17 18 19
```

I can get the combined levels as a list:

```
lapply(df, levels)

$`Citrus`
[1] "lemon"  "lime"   "orange"

$Cutlery
[1] "fork"  "knife" "spoon"
```

I'm looking for a clever way to loop around the factor columns and applying the map function using the unique levels of each column derived by the lapply statement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you provide an example that more clearly demonstrates the problem? The jump from your example code to the explanation of a more complex case is hard to follow.

Comment: I think I would write your code as `split(seq_along(my.vector), my.vector)`. The way to apply that to a list of factor vectors is `lapply(list_of_factors, function(x) split(seq_along(x), x))`, but you lost me when you jumped from factor vectors to data frames and subset data frames. Could you create a small example with sample input and desired output? 2 or 3 factors,with a length of about 5 each should be plenty.

Comment: Using your new sample input, can you either (a) show your desired output, (b) explain how it is different from the result of the code in my comment above, `lapply(df, function(x) split(seq_along(x), x))`, or (c) ideally both (a) and (b)? Since  you don't show what you want, I have no idea if the guess I left above is right or wrong, and if it's wrong I don't know why.

Comment: Gregor, hey that works!  Thanks!  split(seq... is new to me.  Great insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving comment to answer:

```
## this code
vec.levels <- levels(my.vector)
factor.vectors <- purrr::map(vec.levels, function(x) which(my.vector == x))
## seems like an over-complicated version of this
split(seq_along(my.vector), my.vector)
```

In general if you want to apply a function to multiple columns of a data frame, we use `lapply`:

```
# your version
lapply(df, function(fac) {
  vec.levels = levels(fac)
  purrr::map(fac, function(x) which(fac == x))
})

# my version
lapply(df, function(x) split(seq_along(x), x))
```